# Definition of a function and the notation $f:A\to B$.

Tags: soft-question, education, math-history

In some textbooks on analysis, I have encountered a definition of function/mapping that distinguishes the terminology *mapping on $A$ to $B$* and *mapping from $A$ to $B$*; the first one refers to a function with domain $A$, the second to a function with domain $A'\subseteq A$. Furthermore, the notation $f: A\to B$ is sometimes used in the second meaning where the domain might be a proper subset of $A$.

My question is: is the second, nonstandard convention, just a local nuance of older books in Czech Republic where I live, or is/was there such convention in the past and/or in a larger geographical and cultural area?

Comment: All the literature I know, unless stated otherwise (which does happen, but rarely; it makes sense if the whole book is about [partial functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)...), by $f : A \to B$ denotes a function with domain $A$. A common notation for partial functions is $f : A \rightharpoonup B$ (note the incomplete arrow) or $f: A ↛ B$ (note the slash), however, it varies.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, the term function is used for the case where the entire $A$ is the domain. The concept you mention is usually called a 'partial function' from $A$ to $B$. When it comes to notation, I'm not quite sure if there's just one way to denote it. I think I've come across two different notations so far, neither of which I can now find in LaTeX symbol lists. One would be to write a vertical line through the $\to$ in $f:A\to B$ and the other would erase the middle part of the very same arrow to yield something like $f:A-\to B$, but not quite as long.

Comment: The comment by @dtldarek suggests there's no such thing as standard notation, since both options he mentions are different from what I've seen.